# How to add additional label in prometheus metric to get value of that label

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, alert

Using this metric we get below output.

```
(kube_pod_init_container_status_restarts_total{container="container_name"}) * on(namespace, pod) group_left(label_operator) kube_pod_labels
```

Output:

```
{app_kubernetes_io_instance="monitoring", app_kubernetes_io_managed_by="Helm", app_kubernetes_io_name="kube-state-metrics", container="container_name", helm_sh_chart="kube-state-metrics-3.5.2", instance="10.20.50.118:8080", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", kubernetes_name="monitoring-kube-state-metrics", kubernetes_namespace="monitoring", kubernetes_node="gke-dev2-nap-e2-highcpu-1", namespace="demo-namesapce", pod="pod_name", uid="9de"}
```

We want to add one more label that should be get using above mentioned query.

Example:

```
{app_kubernetes_io_instance="monitoring", app_kubernetes_io_managed_by="Helm", app_kubernetes_io_name="kube-state-metrics", container="container_name", helm_sh_chart="kube-state-metrics-3.5.2", instance="10.20.50.118:8080", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", kubernetes_name="monitoring-kube-state-metrics", kubernetes_namespace="monitoring", kubernetes_node="gke-dev2-nap-e2-highcpu-1", namespace="demo-namesapce", pod="pod_name", uid="9de", operator="operator_node"}
```

Comment: Marco, it would be great if you could add more details to the question, since it isn't clear enough.